# How to make a webpage with a large centered "main text column" and two smaller empty ones on the sides with different backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, background-color

This might sound like a weird question since I don't really know how to describe it, but what I want to do is to have like 15% of empty space on both sides of my webpage. This is easily achieved in dreamweaver by setting a 15% padding on both sides of the #body. But I want the empty spaces on the sides to have backgroundcolors...

So for example I want the "main part" of the page to be white, and the 15% on the sides to be light blue.

Also, I would like to know how to (and not to) make this affect the topbanner. I have not decided if I want the top banner to stretch over the whole screen or be centered like the rest yet.

Thanks！！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting a div inside a containing div. The containing div needs to be 100% width of the page and the one inside needs to be 70% with `margin: 0 auto` set to center it, giving you a 15% gutter.

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
  /* make background sky blue */
  padding: 0;
  /* remove normal browser padding */
  margin: 0;
  /* remove normal browser margin */
}
header {
  height: 50px;
  /* Just some predefined height */
  background: red;
  /* set a different background */
  margin: 0;
  /* remove spacing outside element */
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  /* set width to 70% of page width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* set margin top & bottom to 0 but the the left and right will centre align */
  background: white;
  /* set white background */
  text-align: center;
  /* center the text */
}
```

```html
<header>
  Left Blank
</header>

<div class="content">
  This is 70% of the width with 15% spacing on each side
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make the blue on the side continue down the whole page? Now its only 2 small blue lines on the top with the text you wrote in it. Also, how to I make sure that all the information I write on the page ends up in the middle and not on the sides?

Comment: See my amended answer. I also added comments to show you what each CSS line does to change the page.